# AllJoyn control panel in Windows 10 iot (DSB)

Tags: alljoyn, windowsiot

I searching for samples / snippets of an AllJoyn control panel for windows 10 IOT.
Either a DSB template based application where the Device offers a control panel or a controller using a control panel would be fine.
Even "good documentation" would be helpfull.
But I can find nothing about it - except (of course) the alljoyn documentation itself - which doesn't really help me with implementing a controller / controlle in Windows 10 IoT